# NSPopover show relative to NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstatusitem, nspopover

This is my code:

```
if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
    if let b = statusItem.button {
        popover.showRelativeToRect(b.bounds, ofView: b, preferredEdge: .MinY)
    }
} else {
}
```

The `else` block is for OS X Mavericks because `NSStatusItem.button` is not available. Is there a simple way of showing the popover relative to the status item? If not, is it possible to show the popover in the center of the screen instead without the arrow?

Comment: sorry but I haven't work with NSPopover in a while but .... whats the problem? your if seems ok for 10.9 as well

Comment: ach I get it, it is about the button....

Answer (score 1):

before you had access to the statusitem button you had to provide your own view. **Then all works the same**

---

to retain the original behaviour, draw a custom view that looks like a status item ;)

e.g.

```
@interface DDQuickMenuStatusItemView : NSView
@property(weak) NSStatusItem *item;
//...
@end


@implementation DDQuickMenuStatusItemView

//...

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSImage *image = nil;
    if(self.item) {
        [self.item drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:self.bounds withHighlight:NO];
        image = self.item.image;
    }

    if(image) {
        NSRect r = self.bounds;
        r.size = [image size];
        r = [self.class centerRect:r inRect:self.bounds];
        r = [self centerScanRect:r];
        [image drawInRect:r fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
    }
}

#pragma mark -

+ (CGRect)centerRect:(CGRect)rect inRect:(CGRect)inRect
{
    CGRect result = rect;
    result.origin.x = inRect.origin.x + (inRect.size.width - result.size.width)*0.5f;
    result.origin.y = inRect.origin.y + (inRect.size.height - result.size.height)*0.5f;
    return result;
}

@end
```

Note that the view is a sample and not production ready ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I'm a Swift newbie and can't work on the code yet, that's why I thought of just showing the popup in the center of the screen, which should be very simpler than this I think. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Im afraid .. that I don't know right now. I can try tonight - I can also provide a swift implementation of the above then just in case